# How to split a list in flutter by summation of the elements in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, split

I want to split a list eg L=[1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2] into sublist in flutter according to the cumulative sum of the elements equal to 4. i.e the list should be split as S=[[1,2,1],[2,2],[1,1,2]]

I am working on something similar such that I have a list of type map, I want to sum the first consecutive new unit value from the list such that if the first consecutive numbers are 30, I will split it and add the remainder of the last element to the next list

eg. I have this list

> [[{id: FG00017, newunit: 20, product: {category: Ball Foods, productname: GP Semovita 4 x 2.5kg - New Pack!, itemID: FG00017, active: 1, minorderqty: 1, price: 4010, netweight: 0, unit: Bags, bagcount: 100, image: "", locationID: Apapa, locationname: Apapa}, items: 2000}, {id: FG00018, newunit: 10, product: {category: Ball Foods, productname: GP Semovita 2 x 2.5kg - New Pack!, itemID: FG00018, active: 1, minorderqty: 1, price: 2070, netweight: 0, unit: Bags, bagcount: 200, image: "", locationID: Apapa, locationname: Apapa}, items: 2000}, {id: FG00032, newunit: 1, product: {category: Ball Foods, productname: GP Goldenvita 4 x 2.5kg - New Pack, itemID: FG00032, active: 1, minorderqty: 1, price: 3445, netweight: 0, unit: Bags, bagcount: 100, image: "", locationID: Apapa, locationname: Apapa}, items: 100}]],

the first two consecutive new unit when summed is 30 so I split it like this

> [[{id: FG00017, newunit: 20, product: {category: Ball Foods, productname: GP Semovita 4 x 2.5kg - New Pack!, itemID: FG00017, active: 1, minorderqty: 1, price: 4010, netweight: 0, unit: Bags, bagcount: 100, image: https:, locationID: Apapa, locationname: Apapa}, items: 2000}, {id: FG00018, newunit: 10, product: {category: Ball Foods, productname: GP Semovita 2 x 2.5kg - New Pack!, itemID: FG00018, active: 1, minorderqty: 1, price: 2070, netweight: 0, unit: Bags, bagcount: 200, image: https:, locationID: Apapa, locationname: Apapa}, items: 2000}], [{id: FG00032, newunit: 1, product: {category: Ball Foods, productname: GP Goldenvita 4 x 2.5kg - New Pack, itemID: FG00032, active: 1, minorderqty: 1, price: 3445, netweight: 0, unit: Bags, bagcount: 100, image: https:, locationID: Apapa, locationname: Apapa}, items: 100}]],

Answer (score 0):

Is there any credit for unnecessary complexity? If so, a `sync*` function can be used.

```
void main() {
  print(parcel([1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2].iterator));
}

Iterable<List<int>> parcel(Iterator<int> input) sync* {
  List<int>? group;
  while (input.moveNext()) {
    group = (group ?? <int>[])..add(input.current);
    if (group.reduce((v, e) => v + e) >= 4) {
      yield group;
      group = null;
    }
  }
}
```

What to do with any members of the input that don't complete a group of at least 4 is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you sir, working in on something similar

Comment: Updated the question to my requirements, please look into it

Comment: It seems you could use identical logic to this answer for your updated question.